# PencilKit Marker Transparency

Tags: swift, pencilkit

In swift I am using Pencilkit to draw on a canvas. However, the marker tool always seems to have some transparency to the color that I am not setting to it. I believe this is a default feature for the marker but I would like to remove the transparency if possible. Does anyone know how this could be achieved. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.